# Hot reload with docker react app doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, docker

i try to use my react app with docker without always rebuild image from my dockerfile. i use a docker-compose file to build my react app but i have always the same error.

PS : im new with Docker so certainly i made some mistakes.

before docker-compose up, i use docker-compose build

when i use docker-compose up i have this error :

```
frontend_1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
frontend_1  | npm ERR! syscall open
frontend_1  | npm ERR! path /app/package.json
frontend_1  | npm ERR! errno -2
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
frontend_1  | npm ERR! enoent
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
frontend_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-03-23T10_26_47_886Z-debug.log
rfid-commisioning_frontend_1 exited with code 254
```

my docker file :

```
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY  . ./ 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3"

services:

  frontend:
    build: Front/RFID
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING="true"
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - "./Front/RFID/:/app"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

[Folder structure Frontend :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeaoD.png)

[Folder Structure Global :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbtej.png)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with your Dockerfile at first glance, but it's missing at least the base image you're using. As you can read in the error, the package.json is apparently not where you're expecting it. You can try to debug this by adding `RUN ls /app/` in the line before the `RUN npm install` (which I guess is throwing the error) in the Dockerfile and rebuilding. You should see at least `package.json` and `package-lock.json` listed. If not, you're copying them from the wrong folder. maybe they are in `src/`? Just guessing

Comment: In the docker-compose file you are mapping /app (in the Container) to ./Front/RFID (on the Host). In the Dockerfile your are copying package.json to /app. 
That should appear than in your ./Front/RFID. Is it there?

Comment: @BertC yes my package.json file is in Front/RFID

Comment: @Taxel I can't see the result of the ls when I rebuild. on the other hand when I build my docker file without going through the docker-compose build then docker-compose up command I don't have any problem and with the Docker extension in Vs code I can see my App folder